# How to run raspberry pi 3 B+ image in VirtualBox or any other Simulation such as Qemu

Tags: python, php, mysql, raspberry-pi3

We made a .img file of the raspberry Pi3 B+ (Linux Debian 9.9) using win32DiskImager software.

On Pi, we made a web application using PHP and MYSQL( max data record: 1 million ) and python application for communication between IoT devices, now we are facing application slow issue, like when user try to open some application options it took time to open and rendering data from the database.

Now I want to utilize my image file to check the hardware capabilities of PI, by run .img file on virtualbox or any other simulator but found that virtualbox does not support the ARM processor.

Please let me know how we can achieve our target.? Can we achieve our target by changing raspberry pi3 to raspberry pi4(4 or 8 GB) Ram?
I already tried to convert .img file to vdi and other format but did not work, I tried to run on qemu but unable to find a raspberry pi processor on qemu as well. We can't install new Debian and do everything again as there are so many things which will take a lot time.

Comment: Not sure if https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/ is any help.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but no luck :(